# How to use Interceptor for change response data in Nest.js

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

I want to use `Interceptor` for change every response data that returns to client.
this is my Interceptor file:

```
import { CallHandler, ExecutionContext, Injectable, NestInterceptor } from '@nestjs/common';
import { response } from 'express';
import { map, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import {snakeCase} from './utils'

@Injectable()
export class ResTransformerInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {

    let request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest()
    return next
      .handle()
      .pipe(
        map((response) => {
          console.log(response)
          response = snakeCase(response)
          return response
        }
        )
      )
  }
}
```

and this is my controller:

```
import { Body, Controller, Get, Post, Res, UseGuards, UseInterceptors } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Response } from 'express';
import { IUser } from 'src/utils/interfaces';
import { ResTransformerInterceptor } from 'src/utils/res-transformer.interceptor';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { RegisterUserDto, LoginDto, OtpDto, ForgetPassDto } from './dto/auth.dto';
import { JwtAuthGuard } from './jwt-auth.guard';
import { User } from './user.decorator';
@Controller('auth')
export class AuthController {
    constructor(private readonly authService: AuthService) { }

    @UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard)
    @UseInterceptors(new ResTransformerInterceptor)
    @Get('/user')
    async show(
        @User() user: IUser,
        @Res() response: Response) {
        const { data, statusCode } = await this.authService.showUser(user.userId)
        return response.status(statusCode).send(data)
    }
}
```

But the response does not change
I should also mention that the `snakeCase` function  works properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `@Res()`to send your response, then whatever you do in the interceptor won't matter. The interceptor can only modify your response if you let Nest send it, by using either `@Res({ passthrough: true })` (and **not** using `response.send()` or `response.json()`) or by returning the value from your controller